# Comments missing new lines when creating a new task

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

I've set up a new flow to create a task item whenever an epic is created in Azure DevOps and assign it to the same epic/iteration/area. I want a bullet point list (or something like it) to show a number of tasks that need to be completed before the epic can be closed.

The task is being created for the new epic and filling in the details correctly. However, the comments are displaying as one continuous line rather than the list that I specified. Microsoft Flow seems to ignore any new lines in the comment.

Basically, how can I get:

```
    * Task 1
    * Task 2
    * Task 3
```

instead of:

```
    * Task 1* Task 2* Task 3
```

To display in the comments?

```
     Do I add <br> or <RETURN> or something?
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's

```
   <br/>
```

to add another line in the comments.